# Has_many through mass assignment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, mass-assignment

I've read through the many threads on this topic and still can't see why my code won't work. I have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :user_roles
has_many :user_groups, :through => :user_roles

#define attributes and validations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_roles
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_groups

attr_accessible <some_attributes>, :user_groups_attributes, :user_roles_attributes


class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :user_group

attr_accessible :role_name

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :user_roles
has_many :users, :through => :user_roles

attr_accessible :user_group_name
```

Via the rails console I'm trying to test creating a user group with associated with a user as follows (before I create the form to do the same)

```
user = User.last
<user details listed>
user.user_groups.create(:user_group_name => "test", :role_name => "test")
```

Gives can't mass assign attribute role_name. If anyone can see what I've done wrong I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: Where is role_id coming from? Is it a column in one of your tables? Normally you'd have a `belongs_to :role` relationship somewhere, but I don't see that.

Comment: Have you tried moving attr_accessible above the accepts_nested_attributes_for line?

Comment: Sorry - that is a typo - have corrected to role_name

Comment: Does the ordering make a difference? I hadn't realised that. I'll try it and see if it works